# 10.11 NSCollectionView: "could not load the nibName: NSCollectionViewItem in bundle NSBundle"

Tags: macos, xcode7, nib, cocoa-bindings, nscollectionview

I want to use a NSCollectionView with the new API model from Swift according to https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/AppKit/RN-AppKit/#10_11CollectionView. Since I prefer doing as much as possible in IB, I want to use the Content binding and follow the section *Binding Content to an NSCollectionView (New since WWDC Seed)* on the linked page.

I've pulled an NSCollectionView from the object library into my storyboard, then deleted the additionally generated *prototype* segue via the connections inspector, and also removed the generated NSCollectionViewItem. Then, I've set the Collection View's layout to *Flow*, and connected the collection view to an outlet of my view controller.

Next, I've created a separate .xib file with Xcode's view template, and put in the necessary views. I've also pulled in a "Collection View Item" object.

Then, I've adjusted the view controller's viewDidLoad method to register the nib with the collection view.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let nib = NSNib(nibNamed: "Item", bundle: nil)!
    collectionView.registerNib(nib, forItemWithIdentifier: "")
}
```

Finally, I've connected my array controller to the Content binding of the NSCollectionView.

However, when I try to launch the app, an exception is thrown:

> [NSNib _initWithNibNamed:bundle:options:] could not load the nibName: NSCollectionViewItem in bundle NSBundle

The exception occurs only if my array has actual contents, so only when CollectionViewItems need to be instantiated.

What am I doing wrong here?

**Sample project here: https://scriptreactor.com/collectionviewtest.zip**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem was that in the Collection View Item's .xib, the *Item object*'s view outlet needs to be linked to the root view. Additionally, the Nib Name needs to be set in the Attributes Inspector of the *Item object*.

Comment: Where did you set the Nib Name? It shows `Not Applicable` when I choose Item Object and Attributes Inspector

Comment: I found it. I should use a CollectionViewItem instead of Object